# How do you get another civilization help you in a war after you are attacked?

Tags: civilization-6

Is it possible to get another civilization to help you when you have been attacked?  I know you can have defensive compacts, but I didn't have them in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the release of the [spring patch](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/spring-patch-notes.632218/) you can now ask other players to join in a war you're already in.

Comment: I wonder how this actually works, that is, the conditions that favour a civ joining a war (or not)?